# Segregate error on the basis of status in datadog

Tags: kotlin, grpc, monitor, datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have a datadog monitor the query for which is written as:

```
default_zero(sum:trace.grpc.server.errors{service:name_of_service,env:lab}.as_count())
```

The above query tracks the erros for my service and based on the alerts sends the appropriate notifications. Now, there are a few errors regarding which I am aware and wish not to be notified, how can I do that? I tried using rpc.grpc.status_code key with value invalid but datadog does not allow me to use rpc.grpc.status_code in my query. Is there any was by which I can ignore all PERMISSION DENIED and CANCELLED errors from this monitor?